# how to get users Amazon Cognito with android sdk

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am creating an android application in which I need to get cognito user list. amazon documentation refer to use the UserList api.But I am looking for a solution to do via android sdk.Is there any way to get user list using android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the AWS Java SDK (using [gradle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html)) instead of the AWS Android SDK (which has a limited support of the API).

In `com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.AbstractAWSCognitoIdentityProvider` you will find [listUsers()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/AbstractAWSCognitoIdentityProvider.html#listUsers-com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.ListUsersRequest-)

Note: *Remember to only include the modules you need, so your Android app doesn't get too big in size for no reason.*